# Showing that $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{(\ln x)^2}$ is an increasing function for $x \ge 10$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, solution-verification

I am trying to show that $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{(\ln x)^2}$ is an increasing function for $x \ge 10$

Please let me know if any of these steps are wrong:

(1)  Using the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) with $g(x) = x$ and $h(x) = (\ln x)^2$:

$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

(2) Using the [exponent rule](https://mathvault.ca/exponent-rule-derivative/) for derivatives with $s(x) = \ln x$:

$$h'(x) = (s(x)^2)' = s(x)^2\left(s'(x)\dfrac{2}{s(x)}\right) = 2s(x)s'(x)$$

(3) $s'(x) = \dfrac{1}{x}$ so that:

$$h'(x) = \dfrac{2\ln(x)}{x}$$

(4) With $g'(x) = 1$, it follows that:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{(\ln x)^2 - \frac{2x\ln(x)}{x}}{(\ln x)^4} = \dfrac{(\ln x)^2 - 2\ln(x)}{(\ln x)^4}$$

(5)  It is increasing at $x=10$ since:

$$\dfrac{(\ln 10)^2 - 2\ln(10)}{(\ln(10))^4} > 0.24 > 0$$

Are these steps correct?  Did I make any mistakes?  Am I missing any details?

Comment: You're not wrong, but the conclusion can be strengthened. $\ln(x)-2>0$ for $x>e^2\approx 7.3$.

Comment: Great point.  Thanks.

Comment: the derivative has a common factor that can be taken out, becomes $$  \dfrac{\ln x - 2}{(\ln x)^3}$$

Comment: Thanks, Will.  I missed that!  :-)

Comment: $f(x)$ is strictly increasing at $x=10,$ which means there exists $r>0$ such that $f(y)<f(10)<f(z)$ whenever $10-r<y<10<z<10+r,$ which follows from $f'(10)>0. $ But you did not show that $f'(x)>0$ for $all$ $x\ge 10.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier approach: Introduce substitution $x=e^t$. Notice that $x(t)$ is monotoniously increasing. Now you have to prove that the following function is increasing:

$$f(t)=\frac{e^t}{t^2}$$

This is obvious from:

$$f'(t)=\frac{t^2e^t-2te^t}{t^4}=te^t\frac{t-2}{t^4}$$

The first derivative is positive for $t>2$ i.e. for $x>e^2\approx 7.39$.