# Is this a valid proof for Sylvester-Schur Theorem for the case $n \ge 8$ and $x \ge 2n$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, solution-verification

Below is my effort to provide an alternative argument for the [Sylvester-Schur Theorem](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/on-a-theorem-of-sylvester-and-schur/7A13C0E854FA6A796BC3130C05497E18) that is simpler than [this one](https://users.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1934-01.pdf) by [Paul Erdős](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Erd%C5%91s).

Please let me know if I made any mistakes or if any point is unclear.

The argument uses the following lemma:

**Lemma**:  For integers $n \ge 13$ and $x \ge 2n$:

$${x \choose n} > \dfrac{x!}{[x - \pi(n)]!}$$

(1) For $n \ge 8$, it is straight forward to show that:

$$n > (\ln n)^2$$

> Note:  See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3667354/48606) for details on $n > (\ln n)^2$

(2) For $n \ge 5$, it [follows](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668509/48606) that $(2n-2)\ln n > 2.25506n$ so that:

$$2n\ln n - \left(\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}\right)\ln n - 1.25506n > (2n-2)\ln(n) - 1.25506n> 2.25506n - 1.25506n= n$$

(3) $2n\ln n - \left(\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}\right)\ln n - 1.25506n > (\ln n)^2$

(4) $(2n-1) - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n} > \ln n + \dfrac{1}{n+1}$

(5) Multiplying $n+1$ to both sides
$$(n+1)\left[(2n-1) - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right] > (n+1)\ln n + 1$$

(6) Multiplying $\ln n$ to both sides:

$$(n+1)[(n-1)\ln n - 1.25506n] > (\ln n)[(n+1)\ln n -n + 1]$$

(7) $n+1 > \left(\dfrac{\ln n}{(n-1)\ln n - 1.25506n}\right)\left[(n+1)\ln n - (n-1)\ln e \right]$

(8) $\sqrt[n - 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}]{\left(2n - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\left(2n-1 - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\dots(n+1)} > (n+1) > \sqrt[n - 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}]{\dfrac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}}}$

(9) Since $n! \le \dfrac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}}$, it follows that:

$$\sqrt[n - 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}]{\left(2n - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\left(2n-1 - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\dots(n+1)} > (n+1) > \sqrt[n - 1 - \frac{1.25506n}{\ln n}]{n!}$$

> Note:  See Theorem [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lower_and_Upper_Bound_of_Factorial) for the argument that $n! \le \dfrac{n^{n+1}}{e^{n-1}}$.

(10) Since $x \ge 2n$:

$$\left(x - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\left(x-1 - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\dots(x-n+1) \ge \left(2n - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\left(2n-1 - \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}\right)\dots(n+1) > n!$$

(11) Since for $n > 1$, $\pi(n) < \dfrac{1.25506n}{\ln n}:$

$$(x-\pi(n))(x-1-\pi(n))\dots(n+1) > n!$$

> Note: See 3.6, Theorem 2, Corollary 1,from [Rosser & Schoenfeld, 1962](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807)

(12)  $\dfrac{(x)(x-1)\dots(x-n+1)}{n!} > (x)(x-1)\dots(x-\pi(n)+1)$

(13) It follows that:

$${x \choose n} > \frac{x!}{[x - \pi(n)]!}$$

**Theorem**:  For integers $n \ge 9, x \ge 2n$, there exists a prime $p > n$ such that $p | \dfrac{x!}{(x-n)!}$

(1) Let $x,n$ be integers such that $n \ge 9$ and $x \ge 2n$.

(2) Assume that there is no prime greater than $n$ that divides $\dfrac{x!}{(x-n)!}$

(3) Let $\text{lcm}(x-n+1, x-n+2, \dots, x)$ be their [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

(4) It can be shown that:

$$\text{lcm}(x-n+1, x-n+2, \dots, x) \ge {x \choose n}$$

> Note: The argument for this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)

(5) From the assumption in (2), it follows that:
$$\text{lcm}(x-n+1, x-n+2, \dots, x) < \dfrac{x!}{[x - \pi(n)]!}$$

> Note: Where $\pi(n)$ is the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

(6) But then, we have a contradiction since for $n \ge 13, x \ge 2n$, it follows from the lemma:

$${x \choose n} > \dfrac{x!}{[x - \pi(n)]!}$$

Feel free to let me know if any point is unclear or if there is a better way to make the same argument.

---

**Edit:** found 1 mistake in step(2).

This allows me to change the lower bound from $n\ge 9$ to $n \ge 8$, I believe that it has now been fixed.

**Edit 2:**

Step(8) does not follow from step(7).  I will update the argument if I can.  At this point, it is invalid.