# For $x \ge 5$, does it follow that $(2x-2)\ln x > 2.25506x$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, solution-verification

Am I correct that this is established if I can show that:

- It is true for $x \ge 5$
- $f(x)=\dfrac{(2x-2)\ln x}{2.25506x}$ is increasing for $x \ge 5$.

If this assumption is correct, then the answer is yes since:

It is true for $x = 5$ since:

$$2(5)-2)\ln(5) > 12.8 > 11.3 > 2.25506\times5$$

It is increasing for $x \ge 1$ since:

(1)  Using the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) with $g(x) = (2x-2)\ln n$ and $h(x)=2.25506x$:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{[h(x)]^2}$$

(2) Using the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) with $s(x) = (2x - 2)$ and $t(x) = \ln(x)$

$$g'(x) = s'(x)t(x) + s(x)t'(x) = 2\ln(x) + \dfrac{2x - 2}{x} = \dfrac{2x\ln(x) + 2x - 2}{x}$$

(3) So that:

$$f'(x) = \frac{(2x\ln(x) + 2x - 2)2.25506 - (2x-2)\ln(x)(2.25506) }{(2.25506x)^2} = \frac{2x\ln(x) + 2x - 2 - (2x-2)\ln(x)}{2.25506x^2} = \frac{2x - 2 +2\ln(x)}{2.25506x^2}$$

(4)  $\frac{2x - 2 +2\ln(x)}{2.25506x^2} > 0$ for $x \ge 1$

---

Edit: Change $n$ to $x$ in the second bullet based on a comment.

Comment: Did you mean  $\ln x$ in the second bullet?  Otherwise, what is $n$?

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  I'll fix it.  :-)

Comment: Actually true when $x \gt  4.3317$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much easier is to note $ \ln 5 \gt 1.6$ so
$$(2x-2) \ln x \gt 3.2x-3.2 =2.22506x +(0.97494x-3.2) \gt 2.22506x$$ when $x \gt 5$

Your approach of showing that the ratio starts out greater than $1$ and is increasing is fine, too.