# Showing that $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{(2\ln x)^2}$ is an increasing function for $x \ge 8$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, solution-verification

I apologize for the repetition.  I asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3667354/48606) before.

I was trying to generalize the result.  Does the following reasoning also work to show that $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{(2\ln x)^2}$ is an increasing function for $x \ge 8$

Please let me know if any of these steps are wrong:

(1)  Using the [quotient rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) with $g(x) = x$ and $h(x) = (2\ln x)^2$:

$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{(h(x))^2}$$

(2) Using the [exponent rule](https://mathvault.ca/exponent-rule-derivative/) for derivatives with $s(x) = 2\ln x$:

$$h'(x) = (s(x)^2)' = s(x)^2\left(s'(x)\dfrac{2}{s(x)}\right) = 2s(x)s'(x)$$

(3) $s'(x) = \dfrac{2}{x}$ so that:

$$h'(x) = \dfrac{8\ln(x)}{x}$$

(4) With $g'(x) = 1$, it follows that:

$$f'(x) = \dfrac{(2\ln x)^2 - \frac{8x\ln(x)}{x}}{(2\ln x)^4} = \dfrac{(2\ln x) - 4}{(2\ln x)^3}$$

(5)  It is increasing at $x\ge 8$ since:

$$\dfrac{(2\ln 8) - 4}{(2\ln(8))^3} > 0.0022 > 0$$

Are these steps correct?

---

Edit:  I changed step(5) to $x\ge 8$ since that is my goal.

It looks like my result may be correct for $x=8$ but insufficient for $x \ge 8$.

---

Edit 2:  Made a fix based on John Omielan's comment.

Comment: Looks OK to me, except that (5) does not suffice if you wish to show that $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 8$ (not just $x=8$).

Comment: Thanks.  You caught exactly what I was trying to show.  How would I prove that it is true for $x\ge 8$?

Comment: Answer : to know the sign of the quotient $\frac{2\ln(x)-4}{(2\ln(x))^3}$, look at the sign of the numerator & denominator

Comment: @LarryFreeman In your step #$5$, you have a $(2\ln 8)^2$ term but you have only a corresponding $(2\ln x)$ term in your step #$4$. Note I may have made a mistake, but I got $\approx 0.0022$ for the correct value, and $\approx 0.1847$ for your expression. Regardless, the key issue is that $\ln x$ is an increasing function, and $\ln 8 \approx 2.079$, so $\ln x - 2 \gt 0$ for $x \ge 8$. Also, since $\ln x \gt 0$, your denominator will be positive.

Comment: Thanks, John.  I think that's a mistake.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy, for $x \ge 8$, won't both the numerator and denominator be positive?  What additional detail would make the argument sufficient?  Thanks very much.  :-)

Comment: Yes, it suffices to show that the numerator & denominator are both positive, no additional detail is required. The sign of the denominator is clear as explained by John Omielan, and for the numerator you use $2\ln(x)-4 \geq 2\ln(8)-4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost reached there. You will just have to modify your step 5.

$$f'(x)=\frac{2(ln\ x-2)}{8(ln\ x)^3}$$ 
$$f'(x)=\frac{ln\ x-2}{4(ln\ x)^3}$$

We know that $ln\ x>0\  \forall x>1$ and hence for all $x\ge8$. Therefore its cube, $(ln\ x)^3$ is also positive $\forall x\ge8$. That makes the denominator of $f'(x)$ positive $\forall x\ge8$.

Also, $ln\ x$ is a strictly increasing function as its first derivative, $\frac{1}{x}$ is positive in all its domain, i.e., $\forall x>0$.

We also know that $ln\ 8=2.079... >2$, and by the definition of an increasing function we can conclude that $ln\ x\ge ln\ 8>2, \forall x\ge 8$.
$$\implies ln\ x-2>0, \forall x\ge8$$
Hence, we also established that the numerator of $f'(x)$ is positive $\forall x\ge8$.

A rational function is positive if and only if its numerator and denominator functions have the same sign.

Since both its numerator and its denominator are always positive, and hence have same sign, $\forall x\ge8$ we can conclude that $f'(x)$ is positive in the same interval.

Hence proved that $f(x)$ is increasing $\forall x\ge8$